# Laravel and facebook sdk v4 : Get a not found Facebook class

Tags: php, laravel-4, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have been looking for a while and didn't found something that help me.
I had an the composer.json file the require:

```
"facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"
```

I then ran the composer install and update comand.
It added in vendor a facebook folder with a facebook-php-sdk-v4 folder in it.
but when trying to call the facebook class in my routes file, It throw me a "not found error"

here's my routes.php

```
Route::get('login/fb', function() {
    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $params = array(
        'redirect_uri' => url('/login/fb/callback'),
        'scope' => 'email',
    );
    return Redirect::to($facebook->getLoginUrl($params));
});
```

Anyone please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, this is because the Facebook class is now deprecated in facebook SDK v4 and above. You better start with the minimal example they have on their developers page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

A couple of points, make sure to add facebook into the searchable include paths under your composer directory for laravel:
$vendorDir . '/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src',

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add a facebook.php file to your config folder: It should contain something like this:

```
return array(
        'appId' => '************',
        'secret' => '************************'
    );
```

The line **Config::get('facebook')** is trying to get your facebook config file.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to tell that I also added this in a php file called facebook under my config folder.
The instruction that doesn't work is 'new Facebook'.
It tell that it doesn't know that class

Comment: Did you follow these instructions: http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/integrating-facebook-login-into-laravel-application/

Comment: YES ! that the tutorial that I follow